# Deploying Windows app directly to Surface without going through the store

Tags: windows-store-apps

I’ve built a windows app using Cordova and I want to deploy it privately on my Window Surface Pro.

I can deploy it for testing purposes with the developer certificate that is being generate automatically, but it’s only valid for 90 days. Is there a way to premaritally deploy apps on Surface Pro or at least extend the 90 days period?

Thanks

Comment: The term you're looking for is "side-loading". Search on that and you'll find several threads. Check the dates though. Side-loading keys got easier to acquire around the Windows 8.1 Update last spring and will again in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to go in `Project -> Windows Store -> Create Application Packages`

Then select "No" on the first page. You can leave everything else as it is and click next and create.

This will give you 2 files which you need to copy to your Windows Surface. Once this is done go look in the folder that was created and run the *Powershell* situated inside. Your application is now installed on your device

Go take a look [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx) for more detailed informations